# Example of a Boolean Expression that Evaluates to NULL

Tags: sql, database, oracle12c

I understand that in the SQL language (at least in Oracle Database 12c, the RDBMS that I am familiar with,) that boolean expressions can evaluate to true, false, or NULL. I understand when an expression can evaluate to true or false, but I am having trouble understanding how an expression can evaluate to NULL.

Please explain or provide an example demonstrating this.

Comment: Hint: null argument.

Comment: `NULL AND 1=1`.

Comment: I don't know how you "understand" that in Oracle, "boolean expressions" **<anything>**. That is simply false; Oracle SQL **does not have** boolean expressions (expressions of boolean data type), because Oracle SQL does not have the boolean data type, period. Rather, Oracle SQL has **logical conditions** that may evaluate to TRUE, FALSE or UNKNOWN (**not** NULL!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking for an example of something that does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently found this wonderful introduction to `NULL` value:
http://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic

Some quotes:

> The SQL null value basically means “could be anything”. It is therefore impossible to tell whether a comparison to null is true or false.
>
> ...
>
> The result of each of the following comparisons is therefore unknown:
>
> ```
> NULL = 1
> NULL <> 1
> NULL > 1
> NULL = NULL
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Another way to look at it is to mentally replace each null with a call to a random() function.